# Can we use launchd or some other boot-time process to bypass SIP?

Tags: startup, security, launchd

Anything that bypasses SIP is obviously a security problem, so I'm guessing the simple answer is "hell, no!"  However …

**Is there any time at the beginning of the boot process when SIP is not enabled?  And is there anything that can take advantage of that which is also unchangeable after SIP is enabled?**

But either design or errors make it a major pain to add characters to Press And Hold.  You have to reboot single-user, disable SIP, edit a .plist (which is now binary format), re-enable SIP, and reboot.  **And** do it all over again every time Apple overwrites your change in Software Update.

So it would be a great convenience for this and similar problems to be able to replace a protected file during boot.  But it would also be a security hole to have whatever does the replacement outside of SIP.  (An attacker could change the replacement script to do their dirty work.)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that these things can't be added to the root or user Library? SIP is only part of the story now -- the OS is on a read-only, sealed volume.

Comment: But is it read-only always, or set to that during boot?  If I had dual-boot (I don't), I could have the other O.S. do anything at all to the files that are read-only in MacOS.  The other O.S. would have to handle APFS, but it could be a second MacOS that has SIP disabled.  (Or is SIP something in the PRAM?)

Comment: PressAndHold is controlled by a file in the read-only area and although there can be similar files elsewhere, the read-only one takes precedence.  And if it is removed, PressAndHold doesn't wok at all.  Further, if it is removed, Software Update will replace it.  And even if someone gives me a Yes answer, there's also the issue that Apple keeps changing the _location_ of that plist!

Comment: The ability to bypass SIP during boot would indeed be a security hole. https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/18/a-guide-to-startup-modes-for-intel-and-m1-macs/ has some details about how booting works for both Intel and ARM Macs.